# Spark Join on two RDDs complexity

Tags: apache-spark, join, complexity-theory

Joining two RDDs made of tuples `(Key,Value) -> (String,String)`, which is the complexity of the operation?
I'm using the function described on the official Spark documentation: [link](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd-pysrc.html#RDD.join)